# Оптимизация в Unity

Tags: unity3d, оптимизация

Как можно нагружать меньше систему, если используется много статических объектов с одинаковым материалом. Слышал про скрипт "Combine Children", но для версии 2017.1 , как я понял, его нет. Можете что-нибудь посоветовать? Можно так же подсказать идею и насчет динамических объектов. Как их оптимизировать.

Comment: Могу дать почитать только Chris Dickinson — Unity 5 Game Optimization, 2015. вроде там всякого много обо всём. хотя читается сложно ибо картинок очень мало, голый текст))